# Type casting in MPLABX Harmony IDE

Tags: c, casting, pic, microchip, mplab

I am tryed following code on online C compiler it works properly. but when I'm using this logic in MPLAb X harmony IDE it not working it not printing value of result. it shows:
result=  and stops next code is also not executing

```
char arra1[10]; int data=5008;
  float mul=0.01;
  float result;
  result=(float)data*mul;
    printf("result=%f\n",result);
    sprintf(arra1,"%f",result);
   printf("array=%s\n",arra1);
```

Comment: What means : stop? Which compiler? Which controller? ICD or simulator?...

Comment: I Am using XC32 compiler and ATSAME54 xplained board .

Comment: now I understood where is problem. XC32 complier doesn't support float. What settings should I do for it?

Comment: xc32 supports `float` https://www.adoclib.com/blog/configure-mplab-x-ide-to-enable-float-printf.html